# How to I specify this route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to have a URL like this:

```
/v1/vacations?country=US&year=2017&month=08
```

How do I set the route in Laravel 5.3 and where can I put the controller and logic to accept the query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your route should look like;

```
Route::get('v1/vacations', 'VacationsController@index');
```

then on VacationsController

```
public function index()
{

dd(request()->query());

$query=request()->query(); 

//search database using query

//return view with results
}
```

Query strings can not  be defined in your route since the query string is not part of the URI.
To access the query string you should use the request object. `$request->query()` will return an array of all query parameters. You can also use it as such to return a single query param `$request->query('key')`

Answer (score 0):

You just would check the Request object for the url parameters like so:

```
// The route declaration

Route::get('/v1/vacations', 'YourController@method');

// The controller

class YourController extends BaseController {

    public function method(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $country = $request->country;

        // do things with them...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This pointed me in the right direction. 
I received a Request error though but I think it might be because of the way I declared the object?